# How do I parameterize a reusable code block to update various lists?

Tags: c#

I'm very new to c# programming and this is the first time ever posting a question on this site. I'm trying to write a block of code that updates a List that is also reusable so I don't have to duplicate the code for each list I want to update.

I've spent hours searching this site and the Internet for information about function parameters, parameter passing, passing by reference, and a host of other topics but I can't seem to find an answer that fits. I'm hoping someone here will be kind enough to help me out.

Here's a snip-it of the code I'm trying to write:

```
List<string> userTokenId = new List<string>();

public static void MyFunction()
{
    //Update the list
    string strListName = "MyListName";
    string strDataToAdd = "data";
    ProcessTheList(strTableName);
}

Public static void ProcessTheList(string strMyListName, string strDataToAdd)
{
    MyListName.Add(strDataToAdd);
    recordCtr++;
}
```

I want to pass the name of my list through "strMyListName" and have the Add command add the data contained in the "strDataToAdd" variable to the list. I came up with the code above but it doesn't work. I'm not even sure if this is possible. I get the following error:

> "string does not contain a definition of 'Add' and no extension method
>   'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I know this is a painfully rookie mistake and the solution is probably quite simple to everyone, except a novice like me. Can someone give me a few pointers? I apologize if I've left out any relevant information due to my lack of experience.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just pass the list...

Comment: A list is a type of object that can be passed as a parameter. For example: `void process(List<string> s, int i, object o)`. This will pass the reference of the list to the function to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be passing the name of the list, but the reference of the list, like:

```
ProcessTheList(userTokenId, dataToAdd);
```

And your method would then look like this:

```
public static void ProcessTheList(List<string> myList, string dataToAdd)
{
    myList.Add(dataToAdd);
}
```

You don't need the counter `recordCtr`. The number of elements in the list can be always retrieved with `myList.Count`.
To make the method more generic, to accept lists of different types, you can use generics:

```
public static void ProcessTheList<T>(List<T> myList, T dataToAdd)
{
    myList.Add(dataToAdd);
}
```

If your method will do more than just add an element to the list, then this method can make sense. If you will only add the element to the list, then you can just call the Add method on your list. And not even define method ProcessTheList.

Comment: Awesome! Your answer is perfect. I implemented your suggestions and they worked flawlessly. Thank you.